# Lags / wrong y-coordinates at scrolling the RecyclerView (OnscrollListener)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview, toolbar

i'm struggling with a lag-problem with the RecyclerView.OnscrollListener and the onscrolled-Method. (I want to hide the Toolbar/Actionbar when i scroll the list - WITHOUT Coordinator-Layout)

The numbers which i receive from the onScrolled-Method are correct when i scroll "fast". But when i'm scrolling my list slowly, i receive some "jumps" in the y-axis.

Is this a known issue or am i doing something wrong?
Does anyone have some experience with that?

The used listener is the following one:
https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/michalz/hideonscrollexample/listener/parttwo/HidingScrollListener.java

The log that i get (where u can see the jumps) in my Android Studio is:

```
    01-13 17:21:33.611 D/Ilias: Offset: 0 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 9 *** totalScrolled: 0
    01-13 17:21:33.631 D/Ilias: Offset: 9 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 28 *** totalScrolled: 9
    01-13 17:21:33.641 D/Ilias: Offset: 37 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -5 *** totalScrolled: 37
    01-13 17:21:33.691 D/Ilias: Offset: 32 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -22 *** totalScrolled: 32
    01-13 17:21:33.701 D/Ilias: Offset: 10 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 10 *** totalScrolled: 10
    01-13 17:21:33.711 D/Ilias: Offset: 20 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 29 *** totalScrolled: 20
    01-13 17:21:33.731 D/Ilias: Offset: 49 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -2 *** totalScrolled: 49
    01-13 17:21:33.751 D/Ilias: Offset: 47 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -19 *** totalScrolled: 47
    01-13 17:21:33.761 D/Ilias: Offset: 28 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 11 *** totalScrolled: 28
    01-13 17:21:33.781 D/Ilias: Offset: 39 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 28 *** totalScrolled: 39
    01-13 17:21:33.801 D/Ilias: Offset: 67 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -4 *** totalScrolled: 67
    01-13 17:21:33.811 D/Ilias: Offset: 63 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -23 *** totalScrolled: 63
    01-13 17:21:33.831 D/Ilias: Offset: 40 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 7 *** totalScrolled: 40
    01-13 17:21:33.851 D/Ilias: Offset: 47 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 25 *** totalScrolled: 47
    01-13 17:21:33.861 D/Ilias: Offset: 72 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -7 *** totalScrolled: 72
    01-13 17:21:33.881 D/Ilias: Offset: 65 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -24 *** totalScrolled: 65
    01-13 17:21:33.901 D/Ilias: Offset: 41 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 9 *** totalScrolled: 41
    01-13 17:21:33.921 D/Ilias: Offset: 50 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 26 *** totalScrolled: 50
    01-13 17:21:33.931 D/Ilias: Offset: 76 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -8 *** totalScrolled: 76
    01-13 17:21:33.951 D/Ilias: Offset: 68 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -24 *** totalScrolled: 68
    01-13 17:21:33.971 D/Ilias: Offset: 44 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 9 *** totalScrolled: 44
    01-13 17:21:33.981 D/Ilias: Offset: 53 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 26 *** totalScrolled: 53
    01-13 17:21:34.001 D/Ilias: Offset: 79 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -6 *** totalScrolled: 79
    01-13 17:21:34.021 D/Ilias: Offset: 73 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -23 *** totalScrolled: 73
    01-13 17:21:34.031 D/Ilias: Offset: 50 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 11 *** totalScrolled: 50
    01-13 17:21:34.051 D/Ilias: Offset: 61 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 29 *** totalScrolled: 61
    01-13 17:21:34.071 D/Ilias: Offset: 90 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -5 *** totalScrolled: 90
    01-13 17:21:34.081 D/Ilias: Offset: 85 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -23 *** totalScrolled: 85
    01-13 17:21:34.101 D/Ilias: Offset: 62 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 11 *** totalScrolled: 62
    01-13 17:21:34.121 D/Ilias: Offset: 73 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 31 *** totalScrolled: 73
    01-13 17:21:34.131 D/Ilias: Offset: 104 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -3 *** totalScrolled: 104
    01-13 17:21:34.151 D/Ilias: Offset: 101 *** dx: 0 *** dy: -23 *** totalScrolled: 101
    01-13 17:21:34.171 D/Ilias: Offset: 78 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 37 *** totalScrolled: 78
    01-13 17:21:34.181 D/Ilias: Offset: 115 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 34 *** totalScrolled: 115
    01-13 17:21:34.201 D/Ilias: Offset: 149 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 13 *** totalScrolled: 149
    01-13 17:21:34.261 D/Ilias: Offset: 162 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 33 *** totalScrolled: 162
    01-13 17:21:34.271 D/Ilias: Offset: 195 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 4 *** totalScrolled: 195
    01-13 17:21:34.281 D/Ilias: Offset: 199 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 5 *** totalScrolled: 199
    01-13 17:21:34.301 D/Ilias: Offset: 204 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 3 *** totalScrolled: 204
    01-13 17:21:34.321 D/Ilias: Offset: 207 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 2 *** totalScrolled: 207
    01-13 17:21:34.341 D/Ilias: Offset: 209 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 2 *** totalScrolled: 209
    01-13 17:21:34.351 D/Ilias: Offset: 211 *** dx: 0 *** dy: 1 *** totalScrolled: 211
```

I hope u can help me!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem.

My special problem is based on the "relative" y-axis-coordinates values of a Recyclerview. I explain:

We have a Toolbar on the top of our Activity.
Our Fragment with the recyclerView is "below" the toolbar.

So in our case, the toolbar has an initial height of 224px.
With every calling of "onMoved" inside our OnscrollListener we reduce the height of the Toolbar respective set a translation of the distance scrolled.

So, what happens here?
With every iteration of reducing the height of the toolbar, the "height" of the recyclerView was increased. So the y-coordinate of a 500 px height RecyclerView (for example) isn't of course the same y-coordinate if we increase the RecyclerView on the top-side.

```
    ________________   
1  | Toolbar        | 
2  |                | height: 200px
3  |________________|  
1  | RecyclerView   |  
2  |                |  
3  |                |  <---- y-coordinate of the recyclerView
4  |                |        at this point: 256 (for example)
5  |                |  
6  |                |  
7  |                |  
8  |                |
9  |                |
10 |________________|  


    ________________ 
1  | Toolbar        | 
2  |________________|  
1  | RecyclerView   |  
2  |                |  
3  |                |  
4  |                |  <---- y-coordinate of the recyclerView
5  |                |        at this point: 380 (for example)
6  |                |  
7  |                |  
8  |                |  
9  |                |
10 |                |
11 |________________|
```

Maybe this will help someone of u in the future :)